# inserting html from a record

Tags: php, sql, recordset

OK forgive me for being dumb but im new to this.  I have a record set which contains html tags and formatting with descriptions in eg:

```
<P style="TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 36pt; mso-add-space: auto; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1" class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst>
<SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; mso-fareast-font-family: Symbol; mso-bidi-font-family: Symbol"><SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore">·
<SPAN style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN> <FONT face=Calibri>
Bundle Includes
<?xml:namespace prefix = o ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /> <o:p></o:p></FONT></P> 
 <P style="TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 72pt; mso-add-space: auto; mso-list: l0 level2 lfo1" class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle>
 <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Courier New'">
 <SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore">o
 <SPAN style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN>
<FONT face=Calibri>2 Year Extended Warranty For Toshiba 1 Year Notebook (Inc. Courier Pickup / Return Service) , Suitable for Satellite Pro C665, L730, L750, L770, P770, S750<o:p></o:p></FONT></P>
   <P style="TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 72pt; mso-add-space: auto; mso-list: l0 level2 lfo1" class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle>
  <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Courier New'">
  <SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore">o
  <SPAN style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN>
   <FONT face=Calibri>Toshiba 75W ACAdaptor 3pin19V<o:p></o:p></FONT></P> 
   <P style="TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 72pt; mso-add-space: auto; mso-list: l0 level2 lfo1" class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle>
   <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Courier New'">
    <SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore">o
   <SPAN style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN>
   <FONT face=Calibri>BitDefender Internet Security 2012 OEM<o:p></o:p></FONT></P>  <P style="TEXT-INDENT: -18pt; MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt 72pt; mso-add-space: auto; mso-list: l0 level2 lfo1" class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast> <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Courier New'; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Courier New'"><SPAN style="mso-list: Ignore">o<SPAN style="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN></SPAN></SPAN><FONT face=Calibri>Everki 16" Advance Compact Bag<o:p></o:p></FONT></P>
```

Now I need to insert this into a .php page to write the description with the fommatting.
When I insert it, it just comes up as the raw html.

Again its prob simple to someone so your help would be appriciated

Thanks

Comment: Well, it is raw html..I'm not sure what magic you were expecting, but you need to give us more info and a better explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: how r u displaying the tags in the .php file?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please include the pertinent php code where you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Save HTML data in `Serialize` format, while using it to display `Unserialize` it.

Ref:-
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that your HTML code saved in your database has it's HTML entities encoded. Try calling `$myHTML = html_entity_decode($myHTMLFromDatabase)` on your data. Make sure nothing is escaped either by using `urldecode()` and `stripslashes()`.